# Failed to execute goal antrun plugin while building hadoop

Tags: maven, hadoop, ant

While building the hadoop using maven, I encountered one error that one command in ant script exited abnormally.
more details are in following error.

```
[INFO] Apache Hadoop NFS .................................. SUCCESS [  2.372 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop KMS .................................. FAILURE [  5.222 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common Project ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HttpFS ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS BookKeeper Journal .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS-NFS ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Project ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-api .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-common ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-common .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-tests ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-client ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-applications ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 51.908 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-18T00:01:56+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 77M/771M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (dist) on project hadoop-kms: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: 1
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<exec failonerror="true" dir="/Users/jinteng/work/hadoop-compile/hadoop-2.6.5-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-kms/target" executable="sh">... @ 10:142 in /Users/jinteng/work/hadoop-compile/hadoop-2.6.5-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-kms/target/antrun/build-main.xml
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
```

Comment: what all have you tried to resolve this? have you read build guide fully?

Comment: yeah, thanks for focusing, and I just want to share it after resolving this error

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question for sharing.

Background:
I killed the building process for the slow internet speed while downloading tomcat's tar packet.

Because of the interruption of downloading, the packet is not complete and tomcat-untar.sh would occured an exception while trying to untar the tomcat.

Later, I downloaded the packet separately and pushed it into downloads dir and found it works